# How to play multiple sound?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, playback

I need to play multiple sound files. I have the following code:

My `.h` class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer;
}

- (IBAction)music1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)music2:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)music3:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)music4:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)music5:(id)sender;

@end
```

My `.m` file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)music1:(id)sender {

    if(musicPlayer.isPlaying)
    {
        [musicPlayer pause];
        return;
    }
    if(musicPlayer == nil)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music1" ofType:@"wav" ]];
        musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    }
    [musicPlayer play];
}

- (IBAction) music2:(id)sender {

    if(musicPlayer.isPlaying)
    {
        [musicPlayer pause];
        return;
    }
    if(musicPlayer == nil)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music2" ofType:@"wav" ]];
        musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    }
    [musicPlayer play];
}

- (IBAction) music3:(id)sender {

    if(musicPlayer.isPlaying)
    {
        [musicPlayer pause];
        return;
    }
    if(musicPlayer == nil)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music3" ofType:@"wav" ]];
        musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    }
    [musicPlayer play];
}

- (IBAction) music4:(id)sender {

    if(musicPlayer.isPlaying)
    {
        [musicPlayer pause];
        return;
    }
    if(musicPlayer == nil)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music4" ofType:@"wav" ]];
        musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    }
    [musicPlayer play];
}

- (IBAction) music5:(id)sender {

    if(musicPlayer.isPlaying)
    {
        [musicPlayer pause];
        return;
    }
    if(musicPlayer == nil)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music5" ofType:@"wav" ]];
        musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    }
    [musicPlayer play];
}
@end
```

But this code does not work: only one music file is played. Other file is not.

Also, there is an example:
Music1 playing.

I press the Music2 button -> Music1 end, Music2 start.

How do I need to modfy my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need AVAudioPlayer for each sound:

.h:

```
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
            #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
            #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

            @interface ViewController : UIViewController {
                AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer1;
                AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer2;
                AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer3;
                AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer4;
                AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer5;

NSMutableArray playingMusicArray;

            }

            - (IBAction)music1:(id)sender;
            - (IBAction)music2:(id)sender;
            - (IBAction)music3:(id)sender;
            - (IBAction)music4:(id)sender;
            - (IBAction)music5:(id)sender;

        @end
```

.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    playingMusicArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (void)stopPlayingMusic {
    for(AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer in playingMusicArray)
    {
        [audioPlayer pause];
        [playingMusicArray removeObject:audioPlayer];


    }
}
- (IBAction)music1:(id)sender {


    [self stopPlayingMusic];
    if(musicPlayer1 == nil)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music1" ofType:@"wav" ]];
        musicPlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    }
    [playingMusicArray addObject:musicPlayer1];
    [musicPlayer1 play];
}

- (IBAction) music2:(id)sender {

    [self stopPlayingMusic];
    if(musicPlayer2 == nil)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music2" ofType:@"wav" ]];
        musicPlayer2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    }
    [playingMusicArray addObject:musicPlayer2];

    [musicPlayer2 play];
}

- (IBAction) music3:(id)sender {

    [self stopPlayingMusic];

    if(musicPlayer3 == nil)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music3" ofType:@"wav" ]];
        musicPlayer3 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    }
    [playingMusicArray addObject:musicPlayer3];

    [musicPlayer3 play];
}

- (IBAction) music4:(id)sender {

    [self stopPlayingMusic];

    if(musicPlayer4 == nil)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music4" ofType:@"wav" ]];
        musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    }
    [playingMusicArray addObject:musicPlayer4];

    [musicPlayer4 play];
}

- (IBAction) music5:(id)sender {

    [self stopPlayingMusic];

    if(musicPlayer5 == nil)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music5" ofType:@"wav" ]];
        musicPlayer5 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    }
    [playingMusicArray addObject:musicPlayer5];

    [musicPlayer5 play];
}
@end
```

Comment: And then you end up creating 25 audio players. I'm sure you meant "You need five `AVAudioPlayer`s: one for each sound."

Comment: Thanks you so much.. I missed reviewing :)

What is the second answer my question?

Also, there is an example:
Music1 playing. I press the Music2 button -> Music1 end, Music2 start.
How do I need to write a code?

Comment: Look for my updated answer. It is not the best solution, but it should work

Comment: unfortunately it does not work.

Music1 playing, I press the music2 button, music1 does not stopped.

Comment: How did you start playing Music1?

Comment: I press the button Music1 file, playing Music1 sound
I press the button Music2 file, playing Music2 sound but not stopped music1 sound. 
i want to Music2 sound when it starts, stopped the Music1 sound.

Comment: Try this: change NSArray to NSMutableArray in your .m file (or take my updated code).