# Click on Multiple UIButton how to Play multiple sound at same time duration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, avaudioplayer

I am new in Objective-C. Please help me for this.
I have one viewController which contains scrollview.
scrollView are paging enabled so i have 10 pages on each page i have 30 buttons .
My problem is when click on multiple button i want to play multiple sound..

My code : -

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
if (sender.tag == 1) {
 NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"v1" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer play];
}
 if (sender.tag == 2) {
 NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"v2" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer play];
}
 if (sender.tag == 3) {
 NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"v3" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

problem is when i pressed on buttons only one sound is enable. how to enable multiple sounds ??
please help me...
thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem with above code?

Comment: You haven't described your problem. What's happening when you press multiple buttons?

Comment: @Agent no i want to mix multiple audio sounds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912670/how-to-play-multiple-sound

Comment: @Agent Thanks for the help it's working but for each sound in above link he creates a new instence for AVaudioPlayer and i have a more than 300 UIbuttons.Can i dynamically create AVAudioPlayer for each sound ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First import `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>`

```
    NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundeffect" ofType:@"m4a"];
    NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath : path];

    SystemSoundID audioEffect;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef) pathURL, &audioEffect);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioEffect);
```

In each `UIButton` you need change the path with the sound that you need play.
Hope this help :)